# Android RSS Feeds now displaying blank

Tags: android, rss, xmlhttprequest, android-asynctask

I have previsously parsed this RSS Feed, now that I have updated it to use a AsyncTask it now displays a blank screen instead of a filled listview
CODE:

```
public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {

static String URL= "http://scout.org/rss/feed/all";
static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; 
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
static final String KEY_LINK = "link";
static final String KEY_PUB_DATE = "pubDate";
 String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
         + "/SCOUTS/";




ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.news);
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs =   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    URL= sharedPrefs.getString("news_feed", "-1");
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> libraryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);            
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(CustomizedListView.this, libraryList);        
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
     new MyAsyncTask() .execute();
}

  class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> > {
      private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(CustomizedListView.this);

        protected void onPreExecute() {
           progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Latest WOSM News");
           progressDialog.show();}

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> libraryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

              @Override
          protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... params) {
                  try {
                    new DefaultHttpClient().execute(new HttpGet(URL))
                    .getEntity().writeTo(



                            new FileOutputStream(new File(PATH,"news.xml")));
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                  File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                  File yourFile = new File(dir, "/SCOUTS/news.xml");
                  FileInputStream stream = null;
                try {
                    stream = new FileInputStream(yourFile);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
                  String jString = null;
                  try {
                      FileChannel fc = stream.getChannel();
                      MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
                      /* Instead of using default, pass in a decoder. */
                      jString = Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                    finally {
                      try {
                        stream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    }



                final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> libraryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
                String xml = jString;
                Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); 

                NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);


                    map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
                    map.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESCRIPTION));
                    map.put(KEY_LINK, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINK));
                    map.put(KEY_PUB_DATE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_PUB_DATE));


                    libraryList.add(map);

            }
            return libraryList;}

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {


                list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);            
                adapter=new LazyAdapter(CustomizedListView.this, libraryList);        
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                this.progressDialog.dismiss();

                list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
                          HashMap<String, String> map = libraryList.get(position);

                        Intent in = new Intent(CustomizedListView.this, org.scouts.android.news.Podcast.class);
                        in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, map.get(KEY_TITLE));
                        in.putExtra(KEY_DESCRIPTION, map.get(KEY_DESCRIPTION));
                        in.putExtra(KEY_LINK, map.get(KEY_LINK));
                        in.putExtra(KEY_PUB_DATE, map.get(KEY_PUB_DATE));

                        startActivity(in);
                    }
                }); 



        ;}}}
```

I do not know what is causing it but if you can help, please do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was talking to the web dudes, this was a server side issue.